# How to plot local variable of loop using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am working on a .csv file. I write script to split  sub-columns of **column y** on the basis of ";"  and only print the values of a. The code is correctly printing the desired values.
**I want  to plot the values stored in var (i.e.=23,21,25,12,18,91,21) by using plotly.** I am attaching the sample data and code.

Sample data:

```
   x    y   z
lifelock    a=23;b=25;c=12  USD
lifelock    a=21;b=55;c=23  USD
lifelock    a=25;b=2.c=0    USD
mycityfaces a=12;b=7;c=21   USD
flypaper    a=18;b=25;c=9   USD
flypaper    a=91;b=34;c=21  USD
gauto       a=21;b=77;c=81  USD
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
c=pd.read_csv("data-2.csv")
st="a"
for line in range(c.shape[0]): 
    cells = df["y"][line].split(";")    
    for x in cells:
        if x.startswith("a"):
            var=x[2:]
            print(var)

Output:
23
21
25
12
18
91
21
#plotly code
#import plotly.express as px
#fig = px.bar(x='x',y='**var**')
#fig.show()
```

Comment: Why do you use cryptic names instead of `for line in range(file.size):` `cells = file["y"][line].split(";")` `for cell in cells: ...` for example?

Comment: So is `var` just supposed to be everything lining up with `a` in the `y` column?

Comment: Please refactor that code, it's unreadable. We're probably going to need to see the entire program, too, as well as any input data. See: [mcve].

Comment: @Guimoute kindly consider the updated code which is reusable with sample data.

Comment: @AMC thankyou, I have updated the code kindly consider it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `size`, it returns the number of elements in your DataFrame (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html). Use `c.shape[0]` to retrieve the number of rows (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html).

Comment: @aveuiller that's working perfectly. I updated in question as well can you please tell me how to plot these values by using Plotly? It would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a closer look at your issue, look out for your dataset, the following line is faulty: `lifelock    a=25;b=2.c=0    USD` (a dot appeared instead of a semicolon).

Here is a version of what I guess you were attempting:

```py
import pandas as pd
# Your conversion from c to df is not necessary
# since read_csv will return you a DataFrame already
df=pd.read_csv("data-2.csv")

# We only take the column on which we want to work.
column = df['y']
# We initialize our plot data
x = []
y = []
for line in range(len(column)):
    cell = column[line]
    # the tuple enhance readability a bit with your data
    (a, b, c) = cell.split(";")
    content = a.split('=')
    # If correctly formed, add the data to your plot
    if len(content) == 2:
        x.append(line)
        y.append(content[1])


#plotly code
import plotly.graph_objects as go
# I used a quick example from the documentation:
# https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-hover-text
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=x, y=y)])
fig.show()
```